# The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer

Tags: java, sql-server, security, centos

When my java application tries to connect to SQL SERVER, I get the following error and I don't know the reason.

> HTTP Status 401 - Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The driver could not
>   establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets
>   Layer (SSL) encryption. Error: "java.security.ProviderException:
>   java.security.KeyException".
>   ClientConnectionId:59b52e56-bf2d-4476-a71b-e520f7df81ef

I use a Centos 6.5, Java 7, Tomcat 7, SQL Server 2012.

Could someone can help solving this?